# Python Alphanumeric and Character Comparison

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-analysis

I have a CSV dataset and I'm trying to select all rows where the "INCOME" column is equal to "<=50K" OR ">50K"

This is what I have but it returns only the column names without any rows.

```
df.loc[df.INCOME == '>50K',:]
```

My code basically says select all rows where INCOME column of the "df" dataset is equal to '>50K'

Any help please?

Comment: check whether you have whitespace in INCOME columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with

```
df.INCOME=df.INCOME.str.strip()
df.loc[df.INCOME == '>50K',:]
```

Comment: @David please consider marking the solution as accepted answer if that worked for you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An excellent answer already been exhibited by @Wen, However an alternative approach you can try with element-wise operators as you initially wished in your POST.

### Example DataFrame:

```
>>> df
   NUM INCOME  CAP
0    1    20k    5
1    2    30k    9
2    8    50k    2
3    3    40k    7
4    6    50k    7
5    4    80k    3
6    8    20k    8
7    9    90k   10
8    6    60k    4
9   10    10k    7
```

### Use element-wise logical `OR(|)` :

```
>>> df.loc[ (df['INCOME'] <='10k') | (df['INCOME'] >='50k') ]
       NUM INCOME  CAP
    2    8    50k    2
    4    6    50k    7
    5    4    80k    3
    7    9    90k   10
    8    6    60k    4
    9   10    10k    7
```

OR :

```
>>> df.loc[ (df['INCOME'] <='20k') | (df['INCOME'] =='50k') ]
   NUM INCOME  CAP
0    1    20k    5
2    8    50k    2
4    6    50k    7
6    8    20k    8
9   10    10k    7
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I like this approach as well and I can already see where it will come in handy.